# SSIS Gurus: How do you know if all your data reached it's destination

Tags: ssis

What some of the ways to accomplish this? Have a count of the source rows loaded into a variable then have a sql task check the count in the destination check against that variable? Or use a rowcount?  Just wanted to hear a few ideas to get the ball rolling in my head.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following checks:

- Row count, mentioned above
- No match output rows from lookups have an error destination table with their count, package source and name of lookup that they failed to match on. This table should be empty if there are no errors.
- Conditions to handle null values. Remember SQL (Assuming that's your data source) implements three-value predicate logic by supporting NULL.
- If there are checks on string values I usually capitalize the incoming data in my check (but don't alter the original value) to account for capitalization differences that may occur.
- Any other business requirements that would indicate the results of the process are not complete or valid. This of course will depend on your project.